VLC freezes the image when the mts video file format is played. SMPlayer is doing fine. The problem has been there since (X)Ubuntu 18.04
The video format is mts FHD. MPEG-2 transfer stream.
Resolution: 1920 x 1080
Aspect Ratio: 1.77778
Format: hevc
Transmission rate: 5317 kbps
Frames per second: 50.000000
Selected codec: hevc
Size: 538368 KB (525 MB)
Length: 00:14:40
Demuxer: lavf
Computer:
AMD Ryzen 5 2600, Gigabyte GeForce GT 1030 2G graphics.
Below is a similar topic pointing to some correlations with opening unusual formats.
VLC player doesn't play 4K webm format files image, only audio
VLC (for mts) freezes the image, only the sound comes through. Only once in maybe 100 tries did the image start to move, but after moving the time slider a few times it finally froze the image.
SMPlayer can handle the mts format, but when you move the time slider, it temporarily pixels the image.
The Movies app requests a Teletext decoder, which the automatic software cannot find. After skipping the decoder installation, the application starts playing the video, sometimes it cuts. RAM occupied 21% by three applications: Firefox, Dolphin and Movies.
P.S. 2024.05.23 10:43 At request. Version Ubuntu 24.04 amd64. From the site. https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
